# What are the differences among mutex, semaphore and read write locks

Tags: mutex, semaphore, readerwriterlock

Any real-time scenarios explaining on each would be appreciated.
Is there any other way to handle synchronization apart from these in pthreads.
How do mutex differ from recursive-mutexes(any real-time scenario)?

Comment: "In real time" do you mean for real time applications? (such as games)

Comment: actually read the boost interprocess docs; they are sometimes the same.

Comment: @Borgleader, games are not real-time applications. Not hard real-time at least. Make sure not to mistake high performance and real-time. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing#Criteria_for_real-time_computing)

Comment: @user2601350, It would be nice if you showed some effort. What have you searched and found already? There are many articles regarding synchronization mechanisms on the internet.

Comment: @Shahbaz pendantic argument is useless. I was merely asking for clarification on what type of applications he was referring to.

Comment: @Shahbaz +1 for the joke. OP didn't specify what real-time meant. I was asking for that, both say OSes and games fall into the large category of "real-time applications". While it probably meant the latter this is SO and people wrongly use terminology all the time.

Answer (score 9):

A mutex can be used to protect a shared resource (a variable, a file, a peripheral device) from modifications that could leave it in an inconsistent state.

A semaphore can be used to manage a finite pool of identical shared resources (one important case of this is an *IPC queue*). Threads can take a resource from the pool, put one to the pool, or wait until one becomes available. Note you may still have to use a mutex in addition to a semaphore (to protect the pool data structure itself).

A read-write lock can be used to protect a shared resource that can be either read or written to (modified). All reader threads can access it simultaneously. A writer thread needs exclusive access.

A conditional variable can be used, together with a mutex, to signal events.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aConcurrency_control) can be used to read about most of this.

Comment: according to your explanation, what is the different between a read-write lock and mutex then? I am confused.

Comment: @user3104760  read-write lock is much like a mutex, but there are two kinds of accesses, read and write, whereas with a mutex all accesses are the same. A read-write lock doesn't allow a write access simultaneously with any other access, but allows many read accesses simultaneously. A mutex disallows any access simultaneously with any other access.

Answer (score 2):

This is very plainly answered in the `boost::interprocess` docs

> What's A Mutex?
>
> Mutex stands for mutual exclusion and it's the most basic form of
>   synchronization between processes. Mutexes guarantee that only one
>   thread can lock a given mutex. If a code section is surrounded by a
>   mutex locking and unlocking, it's guaranteed that only a thread at a
>   time executes that section of code. When that thread unlocks the
>   mutex, other threads can enter to that code region:
>
> //The mutex has been previously constructed
>
> lock_the_mutex();
>
> //This code will be executed only by one thread //at a time.
>
> unlock_the_mutex(); A mutex can also be recursive or non-recursive:
>
> Recursive mutexes can be locked several times by the same thread. To
>   fully unlock the mutex, the thread has to unlock the mutex the same
>   times it has locked it. Non-recursive mutexes can't be locked several
>   times by the same thread. If a mutex is locked twice by a thread, the
>   result is undefined, it might throw an error or the thread could be
>   blocked forever. 
>   boost interprocess docs

and

> What's A Semaphore?
>
> A semaphore is a synchronization mechanism between processes based in
>   an internal count that offers two basic operations:
>
> Wait: Tests the value of the semaphore count, and waits if the value
>   is less than or equal than 0. Otherwise, decrements the semaphore
>   count. Post: Increments the semaphore count. If any process is
>   blocked, one of those processes is awoken. If the initial semaphore
>   count is initialized to 1, a Wait operation is equivalent to a mutex
>   locking and Post is equivalent to a mutex unlocking. This type of
>   semaphore is known as a binary semaphore.
>
> Although semaphores can be used like mutexes, they have a unique
>   feature: unlike mutexes, a Post operation need not be executed by the
>   same thread/process that executed the Wait operation.
>   [boost::interprocess docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.semaphores)

boost interprocess doesn't explicitly have things called reader-writer locks, however it does implement them using `shared_locks`, and a `upgrade_lock` and `upgrade_to_unique lock`

> What's a Sharable and an Upgradable Mutex?
>
> Sharable and upgradable mutex are special mutex types that offers more
>   locking possibilities than a normal mutex. Sometimes, we can
>   distinguish between reading the data and modifying the data. If just
>   some threads need to modify the data, and a plain mutex is used to
>   protect the data from concurrent access, concurrency is pretty
>   limited: two threads that only read the data will be serialized
>   instead of being executed concurrently.
>
> If we allow concurrent access to threads that just read the data but
>   we avoid concurrent access between threads that read and modify or
>   between threads that modify, we can increase performance. This is
>   specially true in applications where data reading is more common than
>   data modification and the synchronized data reading code needs some
>   time to execute. With a sharable mutex we can acquire 2 lock types:
>
> Exclusive lock: Similar to a plain mutex. If a thread acquires an
>   exclusive lock, no other thread can acquire any lock (exclusive or
>   other) until the exclusive lock is released. If any thread other has
>   any lock other than exclusive, a thread trying to acquire an exclusive
>   lock will block. This lock will be acquired by threads that will
>   modify the data. Sharable lock: If a thread acquires a sharable lock,
>   other threads can't acquire the exclusive lock. If any thread has
>   acquired the exclusive lock a thread trying to acquire a sharable lock
>   will block. This locking is executed by threads that just need to read
>   the data. With an upgradable mutex we can acquire previous locks plus
>   a new upgradable lock:
>
> Upgradable lock: Acquiring an upgradable lock is similar to acquiring
>   a privileged sharable lock. If a thread acquires an upgradable lock,
>   other threads can acquire a sharable lock. If any thread has acquired
>   the exclusive or upgradable lock a thread trying to acquire an
>   upgradable lock will block. A thread that has acquired an upgradable
>   lock, is guaranteed to be able to acquire atomically an exclusive lock
>   when other threads that have acquired a sharable lock release it. This
>   is used for a thread that maybe needs to modify the data, but usually
>   just needs to read the data. This thread acquires the upgradable lock
>   and other threads can acquire the sharable lock. If the upgradable
>   thread reads the data and it has to modify it, the thread can be
>   promoted to acquire the exclusive lock: when all sharable threads have
>   released the sharable lock, the upgradable lock is atomically promoted
>   to an exclusive lock. The newly promoted thread can modify the data
>   and it can be sure that no other thread has modified it while doing
>   the transition. Only 1 thread can acquire the upgradable (privileged
>   reader) lock.
>   [boost interprocess docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.sharable_upgradable_mutexes)

C++ itself does not yet have `reader-writer locks` (using shared mutexes) but @Howard Hinnet did try to get them in there, if you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14307116/997301) he also provides the code

C++ does not have semaphores, and mutexes are only in the new C++11 standard as far as a I know, which leads to why most of this was about `boost::interprocess`