# shared_mutex C++11 implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, cross-platform

I have found the answer from HowardHinnant in this thread.
[C++11 equivalent to boost shared_mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306797/c11-equivalent-to-boost-shared-mutex)

Unfortunately it seems to make use of the following macro which the Microsoft compiler (VS2015 x64) does not seem to support and the code needs to be C++11 and cross-platform.

```
_LIBCPP_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD
_LIBCPP_END_NAMESPACE_STD
```

I have tried to change it to just

```
namespace std{
...
}
```

Then the compiler complains with the following message.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Column  Source  Suppression
>   State Tool Error  C2244   'std::unique_lock<_Mutex>::unique_lock': unable
>   to match function definition to an existing
>   declaration   shared_mutex_test   c:\documents\visual studio
>   2015\projects\shared_mutex_test\shared_mutex.hpp  1217    1   Build

**Question**, how to solve this. I need shared_mutex / shared_lock functionality and I have to be C++11 compliant. We have decided not to bring in a bigger library like Boost, hence if I could get HowardHinnant's implementation to work cross-platform it would be the optimal solution.

Many thanks.

Ps. 
I have not yet got a reputation high enough to comment on closed questions, hence I was forced to open up this new thread. Feel free to move it into the other thread.

Comment: Just don't put it into the std namespace - it's not a good idea anyway

Comment: So I should just use another namespace? 
I tried that, then I got also a huge amount of errors. Like this

Severity Code Description Project File Line Column Source Suppression State Tool
Error C2923 'ting::shared_lock': 'mutex_type' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'Mutex' shared_mutex_test c:\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\shared_mutex_test\shared_mutex.hpp 1203 1 Build

Comment: Same errors if I completely remove the namespace

Comment: When running clang, `_LIBCPP_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD` is evaluated as `namespace std {inline namespace __1 {`, you could try with this.

Comment: Do you have to use the same solution for *all* compilers? Because VS2015 of course already has a `<shared_mutex>`.

Comment: @UKMonkey not a good idea, and UB ;)

Comment: @Holt thanks but this still gives error. 
Severity Code Description Project File Line Column Source Suppression State Tool
Error C2244 'std::unique_lock<_Mutex>::unique_lock': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration shared_mutex_test c:\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\shared_mutex_test\shared_mutex.hpp 1219 1 Build

Comment: @BoPersson, yes I need to use the same solution, the goal with the framework is that it should be completely cross-platform.

Comment: @JohanHallenberg You can always include `<shared_mutex>` on VS2015 and Howard's implementation for other compilers, as long as the interface are the same.

Comment: @Holt, but we need to be C++11, I assume shared_mutex on VS2015 is not C++11 compliant. Not convinced the interfaces will be exactly the same either I am afraid. In fact we use CMake as a build system and I just let  Cmake generate a VS solution for convenience as I like working in that IDE.

Comment: I get the "unable to match function definition to an existing declaration for" on this code.

template <class Mutex>
    template <class _Rep, class _Period>
    inline
      unique_lock<Mutex>::unique_lock(ting::shared_lock<mutex_type>&& sl,
        const chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>& rel_time)
      : __m_(nullptr), __owns_(false)
    {
      if (sl.owns_lock())
      {
        if (sl.mutex()->try_unlock_shared_and_lock_for(rel_time))
        {
          __m_ = sl.release();
          __owns_ = true;
        }
      }
      else
        __m_ = sl.release();
    }

Answer (score 0):

Solved by just removing all code that failed. It seems it interfered with the available c++11 implementation of unique_lock. Since I can use C++11 I did not need that part of the code.

To fully solve it the complete unique_lock class probably needs to be implemented.