# How to implement a reader/writer lock in C++14

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14, readwritelock

I have a hash table data structure that I wish to make thread safe by use of a reader/writer lock (my read:write ratio is likely somewhere in the region of 100:1).

I have been looking around for how to implement this lock using C++11 ([such as the method here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033188/how-would-a-readers-writer-lock-be-implemented-in-c11)), but it has come to my attention that it should be possible to use C++14's `shared_lock` to accomplish the same thing. However, after looking on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_lock) I have found both `std::shared_lock` and `std::unique_lock` but I don't understand how to use them together (compared to the Boost way which [has simple method calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4820461/1618592) for locking both uniquely and in shared mode).

How can I recreate this relatively simple reader/writer lock interface in C++14 using only the standard library?

Comment: You are looking for [`std::shared_timed_mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_timed_mutex).

Comment: @T.C. Ah thank you! Exactly what I was after :)

Comment: http://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/reader-writer-locks#  might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++14 has the read/writer lock implementation [`std::shared_timed_mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_timed_mutex).

Side-note: C++17 added the simpler class [`std::shared_mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex), which you can use if you don't need the extra timing functions (like `shared_timed_mutex::try_lock_for` and `shared_timed_mutex::try_lock_until`).

However, before using a read/writer lock, be aware of the [potentially harmful performance implications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45580208/783510). Depending on the situation, a simple [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) might be faster.