# How to alternate between concurrent reads and locked single-thread writes to unordered_map in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I have an application where I want to memoize the results of a function across a number of threads. The single-threaded version of the code I want looks something like this:

```
int memoized_method(int arg) {
   int result;
   if (memo.count(arg)) {
       result = memo[arg];
   }
   else {
       result = unmemoized_method(arg);
       memo[arg] = result;
   }
   return result;
}
```

Where `memo` is a `unordered_map`. As I understand it, the `unordered_map` provides guarantees for concurrent reads and for single-threaded writes. My challenge is that, ideally, I need alternate between these modes. This makes it challenging to get the full benefit of the multi-threaded code.

I'll give code to make the dilemma more clear. I could use `mutex` like this:

```
mutex mtx;

int memoized_method(int arg) {
   int result;
   mtx.lock();
   if (memo.count(arg)) {
       result = memo[arg];
   }
   else {
       result = unmemoized_method(arg);
       memo[arg] = result;
   }
   mtx.unlock();
   return result;
}
```

I don't want this option because it requires critical locks every time I access the memo, which would slow down my particular application a lot. Alternatively, I could do something like this:

```
mutex mtx;

int memoized_method(int arg) {
   int result;
   if (memo.count(arg)) {
       result = memo[arg];
   }
   else {
       mtx.lock();
       result = unmemoized_method(arg);
       memo[arg] = result;
       mtx.unlock();
   }
   return result;
}
```

But this isn't threadsafe, since `memo` could end up re-hashing while some other thread is in the middle of accessing it.

Essentially, I want the ability to lock access to the "if" portion of the code only when a thread is in the "else" portion. I would also need the ability to let any threads that are in the "if" block when it gets locked to finish it. I can't see a way to use `mutex` to solve this problem since `mutex` is tied to one particular code block. Is there a tricky way to do it that I haven't noticed? Or are there other lock types I should be aware of?

Comment: Are you targeting a specific platform?

Comment: It has to work on Linux and Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a classic [readers-writers problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem), where many threads can read at the same time, but only one thread can write at a time, and no threads can read while a thread is writing.

I think the "best" solution for a readers-writer lock in C++ is now [C++17's `std::shared_mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex), which you can lock in exclusive mode in the write path and shared mode in the read path. It's designed for exactly this problem. You'll also want a condition variable to let finishing readers wake pending writers and visa versa.

You also definitely want to keep the computation being memoized outside of the critical section.

If you can't use `std::shared_mutex`, there are a lot of other solutions in [Reader/Writer Locks in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/244316) and [How would you implement your own reader/writer lock in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12033188).